# Dynamic links referral code not getting when app install from appstore using dynemic link in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase-dynamic-links

I have shared a dynamic link (referral code deeplink) to another person and he download app from appstore via link and open app that time not getting referral code from this link, Referral code getting blank in dashboard. It's only happen in Live app. If app already installed from appstore and click to dynamic link that time open app and also getting referral code. Can you please help me if anyone know about this issue why not getting code when app first time install using link and open from Appstore?

Comment: What is 'dynemic link' and how are you doing whatever you are trying to do in code?

Comment: @ElTomato Im inviting a new user to install application through link if I install the application through App Store after login the referral code should reflect to web page dashboard. if the application already install then u use the link referral code capturing but if u install application through link referral code not capturing. I don't know exactly what is the issue.